# rails print loop through method invocation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I dont understand why I cant print simple loop simple method invocation. If I call print_message() method, it would work, but if I call print_loop() method as it's written in the code below it wouldnt work. What is the problem, and how could i fix this? thanks!

```
        #app/views/controller/file.js.erb

        <% def print_message()
                "print something"
        end%>


        <% def print_loop() %>   
              <% for i in 0..3 %>
                <%= i %>
              <% end %>
        <%end%>

        if($('#par').is(':checked')){   
              $("#test_div3 #par1").html("<%= print_loop%>")
        } else
             {
             $("#test_div3 #par2").html("<%= 'not checked'%>")
             }
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be defining ruby methods in a rails view to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to the way you're not closing `def print_message()` and you are closing `def print_loop()`

Ultimately, you do not want to write spaghetti code by creating methods in your erb views.

You should create `print_message()` in a helper file like this:

application_helper.rb

```
...
def print_message
  // Loop code in here
end
...
```

and then call this helper method in your erb file. I would personally have the loop printed and then just hide/show depending on what is checked like this:

.html.erb

```
...

<div id="myId" style="display:none;"><%= print_message %></div>

if($('#par').is(':checked')){   
    $("#myId").show();
} else {
    $("#myId").hide();
}
...
```